Is it possible to buffer an RTSP stream on a Ubuntu system, from one (1) original remote source, and re-send streams to >= 1 local/remote clients?
My usecase is this: I have an Raspberry Pi 3B+ with an official Raspberry Pi Camera Module 3, which transmits a H.264 video stream that I receive on another Ubuntu 22.04 headless system (not a Raspberry Pi) by using RTSP on my LAN. It is important that this video stream is of a good quality (I use it in ZoneMinder, and I have gotten it to work well enough, by defining "rtsp://192.168.xxx.xxx:nnnn/streamname" in the ZM camera definition). I sometimes want to look at that stream directly from a completely separate computer or phone, but this seems to be too much for the Pi, since video quality is sometimes lousy and it can affect the Zoneminder stream as well.
My initial idea of how to improve this sitation: I would like the Zoneminder-running Ubuntu system (Ubuntu 22.04, but I have no problem upgrading that one to 24.04 if it would help - But I will only use LTS releases) to be the only recipient of the RTSP stream from the Pi, and in part supply an RTSP "output" to Zoneminder running on the same system, but also provide an open port on which it can present an identical copy of the same inbound RTSP stream to whatever other system that connects to it. Thereby not putting any more load on the Raspberry Pi, regardless of the number of viewers. But I have no idea how to accomplish this. I suppose I want the Ubuntu 22.04 system to act as a video-relaying server.
But I might have missed a different, better way of solving it completely, and if so, please point me in the right direction.
Or, should this video stream to multiple endpoints be so light on CPU/GPU load in the Raspberry Pi that it should not have any problems transmitting multiple copies/versions of the same video feed to multiple endpoints (i.e., there is some problem with the Raspberry that I haven't seen with only the ZM stream active)? Keep in mind that this is a RPi 3B+, with only 1 GB of RAM. (And it is not thermally throttled, and the total CPU load is about 25% on one of the four cores, so I assume it is the GPU part that can't handle it.) Additionally, the RPi is connected via Wifi, but the ZoneMinder-running Ubuntu system has a 1 GbE connection, so Wifi bandwidth could be a constraint if running multiple RTSP streams from the RPi itself.
So if my assumptions/ideas are correct, I would need something on the Ubuntu 22.04 system to accept the RTSP stream from the Raspberry Pi, and either decode/reencode it for whatever other system is receiving it, or preferably, forwarding the stream without any decoding/encoding in order to decrease CPU load. Any ideas on how to solve this?
As for other stuff I've tested: It's not a CPU load/%iowait problem on either the RPi or the Ubuntu 22.04 system with Zoneminder, as verified by htop and iostat. It's not a network bandwidth problem, as verified by bmon/iw dev wlan0 link. It's not thermal throttling. The video is not stored to disk, so it should not be a disk I/O problem. I have not seen any swapping on either system, and there seems to be plenty of available RAM.

One hacky workaround, not solution, is to only use the Zoneminder web interface for viewing this video stream from the RPi, which works more or less, but my ideal solution is to connect to an RTSP stream without logging in to the ZM interface at all.

Please don't put additional information about it in comments. Edit your answer instead.
